# ifconfig does not work in <css /> tags in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, xml, ifconfig

ifconfig does not work in `<css />` tags in Magento 2.

> ## 0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css', attribute 'ifconfig':

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Namespace_Module::css/ultra-megamenu/additional.css"
            ifconfig="ultramegamenu/mobilemenu/hide_blocks_below" />
    </head>
</page>
```

How to fix this ?